# Picking randomly a number with two digits

Tags: probability

Picking randomly a number with two digits that can not be divided by $10$

$\color{gray}{\text{- A) Find the expectation value and the variance of the number}}$

- $B)$ Find the expectetion value and the variance of the digits multiply
- $C)$ Find the probability using [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) that the number will be

$1.$ greater then $85$.

$2.$ greater then $25$.

---

**My attempt for B and C:**

- $A)$

The answer for $A$ is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1639675/203577) but we don't need that for $B$ and $C$.

- $B)$

Let $X$ be the first digit, and $Y$ be the last, so $10X+Y$ is our number.  $X$ and $Y$ are selected uniformly from $\{1..9\}$.

So we are looking for $E[XY]$, $X$ and $Y$ are independent so they are also uncorrelated therefore $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]=5\times 5=\bbox[yellow]{25}$

\begin{align} \operatorname{Var}[XY] &= E[X^2 Y^2 ]-[E(XY)]^2=E[X^2Y^2]-[25]^2 \\  \end{align}

> I don't know how to find $E[X^2Y^2]$

- $C)$

in $A$ we found that $E[10X+Y]=55$ and $\text{Var}[10X+Y]=673.3$

$1.$ So $P(|10X+Y-55|\geq86)\leq\frac{673.3}{86^2}\leq \bbox[yellow]{0.9103}$

$2.$ $P(|10X+Y-55|\geq26)\leq\frac{673.3}{26^2}\leq \bbox[yellow]{0.99600}$

Is my attempt correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (B), *X* and *Y* are still independent and identically distributed, so $E[X^2Y^2] = E[X^2]E[Y^2] = (E[X^2])^2$. By direct calculation (or through the [sum of squares formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number)), $1 + 4 + 9 + 16 + 25 + 36 + 49 + 64 + 81 = 285$, so $E[X^2] = 285/9 = 31$.

Therefore, $E[X^2Y^2] = 31^2 = 961$, and

$$\operatorname{Var}[XY]=E[X^2Y^2]−E[XY]^2=31^2−25^2 = 961 - 625 = 336$$

For part (C), no. Let me do (C), part 1, and leave part 2 as an exercise:

\begin{align} P[X > 85] &= P[X \geq 86] \\
                        &= P[X - 55 \geq 31] \\
                        &= \tfrac{1}{2}P[|X - 55| \geq 31]
\end{align}

The last step is because $X$ is distributed identically above and below $55$. Now we can apply Chebyshev's inequality, but remember that $\sigma$ is not $673.3$, but $\sqrt{673.3} \approx 25.95$.

\begin{align} P[X > 85] &= \tfrac{1}{2}P[|X - 55| \geq 31] \\
                        &= \tfrac{1}{2}P\left[|X - 55| \geq \tfrac{31}{25.95}(25.95)\right]\\
\text{By Chebyshev's inequality} \quad & \leq \tfrac{1}{2}\left(\frac{25.95}{31}\right)^2 \approx 0.35
\end{align}